# Python Pandas DataFrame: conditional column based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, counter

**Description of the problem:**
I'am trying to simulate a machine whose operation mode "B" occurs if "VALUE" is greater or equal to 5 in the last 3 previous time steps- which means "VALUE">= 5 for at least 3 minutes.The Operation mode "B" keeps to be "B" for the next time steps as long as "VALUE" is greater or equal to 5 and is turned to "A" after at least 3 time steps - which means The Operation mode "B" keeps valid for at the next 3 minutes. After 3 minutes the Operation mode "A" is turned on if "VALUE" is less than 5.

**The goal:**
I need an approach using python and pandas to identify the the operation mode  described by "A" and "B" (column: "statusA/B")  based on the values in column "VALUE" and the status "on" and "down" (column: "VALUE<5 --> down, VALUE>=5 --> on").

The conditions have to be considered are as follows:

- case "A" and "B" depend on each other.
- case "B" is occurred if at least 3 "on" previously occurred and the actual VALUE is greater or equal to 5.
- once "B" occurs, the next 3 time steps have to be "B" even if the status is “down” and it keeps to be "B" as long as "on" exists.

**What I did try**:
I tried multiple approaches applying counter for the cases "down" and "on" and tried to track the status based on the counter values but unfortunately it did not work it properly.

| time | VALUE | VALUE<5 --> down / VALUE>=5 --> on | statusA/B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | 0 | down | A |
| 00:01 | 0 | down | A |
| 00:02 | 0 | down | A |
| 00:03 | 8 | on | A |
| 00:04 | 4 | down | A |
| 00:05 | 2 | down | A |
| 00:06 | 1 | down | A |
| 00:07 | 2 | down | A |
| 00:08 | 1 | down | A |
| 00:08 | 5 | on | A |
| 00:09 | 6 | on | A |
| 00:10 | 0 | down | A |
| 00:11 | 10 | **on** | A |
| 00:12 | 10 | **on** | A |
| 00:13 | 10 | **on** | A |
| 00:14 | 11 | down | **B** |
| 00:15 | 2 | down | **B** |
| 00:16 | 1 | down | **B** |
| 00:17 | 3 | down | A |
| 00:18 | 11 | **on** | A |
| 00:19 | 10 | **on** | A |
| 00:20 | 10 | **on** | A |
| 00:21 | 10 | on | **B** |
| 00:22 | 10 | on | **B** |
| 00:23 | 11 | on | **B** |
| 00:24 | 14 | on | B |
| 00:25 | 11 | on | B |

Comment: In case there are 2 `B`s one after the other. Is each of them considered an occurrence or only the first one is considered an occurrence. Because I noticed you replace them with 3 `B`s instead of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modified Solution**. I edited my solution thanks to a subtle point made by dear [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway):

```
import pandas as pd

df2['status'] = df2['VALUE'].mask(df2['VALUE'].shift().rolling(3, min_periods=3).min() >= 5, 'B')

m1 = df2['status'].shift().eq('B')
m2 = df2['status'].shift(2).eq('B')


df2['status'] = (df2['status']
                .mask(m1 | m2).fillna('B')
                .astype(str)
                .str.replace(r'\d+', 'A'))

m5 = df2['status'].shift().eq('B')
m6 = df2['status'].shift(2).eq('B')
m3 = df2['status'].eq('A')
m4 = df2.iloc[:, 2].eq('on')

df2['status'] = df2['status'].mask((m5 & m3 & m4) | (m6 & m3 & m4)).fillna('B')


    index  VALUE  ...                                 resulted statusA/B status
0       0      3  ...                                                  A      A
1       1      5  ...                                                  A      A
2       2      2  ...                                                  A      A
3       3      6  ...                                                  A      A
4       4      3  ...                                                  A      A
5       5      1  ...                                                  A      A
6       6      7  ...                                                  A      A
7       7      7  ...                                                  A      A
8       8      2  ...                                                  A      A
9       9      2  ...                                                  A      A
10     10      3  ...                                                  A      A
11     11      6  ...                                                  A      A
12     12      8  ...                                                  A      A
13     13      8  ...                                                  A      A
14     14      7  ...                                                  B      B
15     15      4  ...                                                  B      B
16     16      4  ...                                                  B      B
17     17      6  ...  A(expected is B because is "on" and at least 3...      B
18     18      6  ...  A(expected is B because is "on" and at least 3...      B
19     19      6  ...  A(expected is B because is "on" and at least 3...      B
20     20      7  ...                                                  B      B
21     21      2  ...                                                  B      B
22     22      9  ...                                                  B      B
23     23      8  ...  A(expected is B because "B" keeps a "B" for 3 ...      B
24     24      7  ...  A(expected is B because is "on" and at least 3...      B
25     25      2  ...                                                  B      B
26     26      4  ...  A(expected is B because "B" keeps a "B" for 3 ...      B
27     27      4  ...  A(expected is B because "B" keeps a "B" for 3 ...      B
28     28      1  ...  A(this true because it is down and the 3 time ...      A
29     29      4  ...                                                  A      A
[30 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to define `m1` and `m2` ;)

Comment: Oopsss, Yes thank you very much. Just added lol.

Comment: The general logic seems fine but you won't be able to reference `status` before it is created, you should probably break your code in two parts, set up the initial `status` and then post-process it.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was so focused on this that I totally forgot that. I will modify now. Thank you very much you are my principle inspiration :)

Comment: @AnoushiravanR
thank you so much for your help. I tried the code for another example and I displayed the result as an answer below. Unfortunately it does not match with what I did expect as values. I described the problem furthermore. Please check this

Comment: @mozway Thank you for your contribution as well

Comment: I think the reason was the question I asked already. I would like to know in case there are 2 Bs one after the other. Is each of them considered an occurrence or only the first one is considered an occurrence. Because I noticed you replace them with 3 Bs instead of 4.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR oups I sorry I did not see that, can you tell me please in which tilmestep in the first example do you mean there is the 2 Bs one after the other?

Comment: `00:14` to `00:16` so I was wondering why `00:17` is not `B` as I first thought when `00:15` is `B` next 2 will be `B`s as well.

Comment: hey @AnoushiravanR, I tried the code for random produced dataframe. Unfortunately it did not work for any dataset :(  maybe I have to think about more general approach for the problem or better explain my problem :/. I thought maybe I can use counter to count the time how much the machine was on and off and based on that find out wether it's warm or cold.

Anyway  I still be thankful for your effort

Comment: Hello Jess. Oh I have no idea why that is the case. However, I suggest you ask a new question by presenting a new sample data that fully represents your original data set. You will have some very good and relevant answers.